# 504 Gateway Timeout when searching OneNote Pages via Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

Microsoft Graph often returns a `504 Server Error: Gateway Timeout` after ~30 seconds when trying to search for a OneNote Page having `links/oneNoteClientUrl/href` ending with a specific string.

Here is the type of query I'm making:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SHAREPOINT_SITE_ID/onenote/pages?$top=1&select=id&$filter=endswith(links/oneNoteClientUrl/href,'ONE_NOTE_PAGE_ID_FROM_ONENOTE_APP%26end')`

I have to do this kind of search as my application takes as an input the link to a OneNote page from the OneNote client application.

The only way I found to find the page's `id` is to search for the url inside `links/oneNoteClientUrl/href` of a OneNote page record.

But this looks like not optimal as Microsoft Graph often times out.

Then is there any way to:

- optimize this query
- find the real OneNote page ID from a copied link from the OneNote app with a different query.